# Laravel Chumper datatables.net

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, datatables

i'm newbie in laravel and  want to use datatables.net. i want to using [chumper](https://github.com/Chumper/Datatable) datatables.net in my projects? after installing that. how to use or update this code for server side (sAjaxSource)?

```
    oTable_categories =$('#showCategories').dataTable({
        "bLengthChange": false,
        "iDisplayLength": 6,                              
        "bScrollCollapse": true,      
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "bAutoWidth": false,
        "sAjaxSource": "server_processing.php",
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "bProcessing": true,

        "fnDrawCallback": function() {
                    clickRowHandler_categories();
            },   
        "fnServerParams": function ( aoData ) {
          aoData.push(
                         {"name": "id"   ,     "value": "id" },        
                         {"name": "title"   ,  "value": "title" },
                         {"name": "join"   ,   "value": "" },
                         {"name": "action"   , "value": "categories" }
          )}
        });  
        function clickRowHandler_categories() {
            $('#showCategories tbody tr').bind('click', function () {
                var aData = oTable_categories.fnGetData( this );
                if ( aData == null ) return false;
                iId_categories = aData[0];
            });
        }
```

i must be define new route such as :

```
Route::controller(
            'mediaManagment','mediaManagmentController',
                array(
                        'getIndex'               => 'mediaManagment.index',
                        'postUpdate'             => 'mediaManagment.update',
                     )
                 );
```

i do not know how to use that.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here, `"sAjaxSource": "server_processing.php"` should contain the `url` of your controller which is sending more/paginated data/records/models so use the `mediaManagment` because this `URL` will invoke the `getIndex()` method. So, use something like this:

```
"sAjaxSource": "mediaManagment" // http://example.com/mediaManagment
```

Do the processing in your `getIndex()` method.

Comment: in `mediaManagmentController@index` i must be use ajax functions or use simply `return View::make()` ?

Comment: This should return the content for `ajax request` so implement it in that way.